# Linear movement between two points that constantly move position

Tags: javascript, linear-algebra

I currently have an issue with my code (written in Javascript); I have arrays objects that keep filling as the time goes. An example of an object:

```
monster.push({
range: 200, 
attackSpeed: 500, 
lastFire: 100,
id: 'ogre',
speed : 50,
pos:[canvas.width*Math.random(), canvas.height*Math.random()],
sprite: new Sprite('images/sheet_characters.png',[508,224],64,64],6,[0])
```

and

```
hero={
attackSpeed: 200,
lastGetHit: Date.now(),
lastFire: Date.now(),
health : 100,
speed: 256, //pixel/second
pos:[canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2],
sprite: new Sprite('images/sheet_characters.png',[256,0],[32,32],8,[0]) };
```

The position field of the objects change quite often and I want to add a function that determines the slope between the monster and the hero (we want the monster to fire at the hero) and then the attack should follow a linear movement.

What I currently have

```
for(var i=0; i<monster.length; i++){
        var mob = monster[i];
        mob.sprite.update(delta); //animatie

        var newPos = moveTowards(mob, hero, delta);
        mob.pos[0] = newPos[0]
        mob.pos[1] = newPos[1]
        if(checkBounds(mob.pos,mob.sprite.size)){
            monster.splice(i,1);
        }
        mobAttacks(mob);


        var attack = enemyAttacks[i]; //atacks updaten
        attack.sprite.update(delta);
        attack.pos[0] = attack.speed * Math.cos(attack.direction)));
        attack.pos[1] = attack.speed * Math.sin(attack.direction)));
        if(checkBounds(attack.pos,attack.sprite.sieze)){
            enemyAttacks.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
```

In this for-loop I can access the position of the monster that fires and also the hero position as it is a global variable. Now the function to attack is :

```
function mobAttacks(object)
{
    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((hero.pos[0]-object.pos[0]),2) +                Math.pow((hero.pos[1]-object.pos[1]),2));
    if( Date.now() - object.lastFire > object.attackSpeed && object.range >= distance)
    {
        deltaY = hero.pos[1] - object.pos[1];
        deltaX = hero.pos[0] - object.pos[0];
        var direction = Math.atan(deltaY/deltaX);
        enemyAttacks.push({ 

        pos:[(object.pos[0]+object.sprite.size[0]/2), (object.pos[1]+object.sprite.size[1]/2)],                     
        direction: direction,
        speed: 128, //pixel/s
        sprite: new Sprite('images/sheet_objects.png', [231,3],[24,24],6,[0])
        });
        object.lastFire = Date.now();
    }
}
```

The angle between both objects is calculated and I make a new object (the attack) with the start position of the monster.

The result is quite odd:

[image]

The slope is off, so is the Y position of the boulder. Also when the hero is on the left side of the monster, there is no boulder to be spotted.

After some hours of tinkering with the code I came to the conclusion that I couldn't solve my current problem.

EDIT:

```
attack.pos[0] += attack.speed * Math.cos(attack.direction)*delta;
attack.pos[1] += attack.speed * Math.sin(attack.direction)*delta;
```

Solved the issue that the boulders are no longer cast from a random position.
Now the angle is a not going negative when I'm in the 2nd or 3rd kwadrant (position left when viewed from the monster perspective)

Comment: Might be an answer: you should look into function `Math.atan2`

Comment: i would rather expect   attack.pos[0]  +=  attack.speed * Math.cos(attack.direction)));  ( += instead of = ). same for y.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get all the trig out of your code, it's unnecessary. Let

```
deltaX = hero.pos[0] - object.pos[0];
deltaY = hero.pos[1] - object.pos[1];
```

then

```
distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
deltaX /= distance;
deltaY /= distance;
```

will make `<deltaX,deltaY>` a normalized vector (one with a length of 1).

Then you can update the position of the attack for `delta` time using simply:

```
attack.pos[0] += attack.speed * attack.deltaX * delta;
attack.pos[1] += attack.speed * attack.deltaY * delta;
```

If you don't have any use for the speed and direction separately, you can also pre-multiply `speed` into `deltaX` and `deltaY` when you initialize the attack, meaning that the update becomes only

```
attack.pos[0] += attack.deltaX * delta;
attack.pos[1] += attack.deltaY * delta;
```

which is nice and simple.